# Pycharm unresolved reference highlighting

Tags: python-3.x, import, pycharm

I'm having difficulties understanding how pyCharm resolves references

I have a project structure like this:

```
ProjectFolder/
   main.py
   libraries/
       my_library.py
       sublibraries/
          my_sublibrary.py
```

Basically libraries is a folder that contains some files (libraries) and some subfolders for better structuring of the libraries

`main.py` imports from libraries ans `sublibraries` without any problem.
`my_library.py` imports some classes from `sublibraries`

```
# inside my_library.py
from sublibraries.my_sublibrary import MyClass
```

However pycharm highlights sublibraries in red with the error

```
Unresolved reference 'sublibraries'
```

This doesn't really affect the execution of the program. It works fine, but the red highlightting is annoying.

I understand that pycharm has ProjectFolder as the current folder and it cannot find subfolders since there's a folder in the middle.

I tried a couple of things:

I can solve this by `mark directory as sources root` but I'm not sure what does this do, and since I'm not commiting .idea files, whoever pulls the repository has the same hightlighting problem and has to manually do the same.

I also tried doing a relative import

```
# inside my_library.py
from .sublibraries.my_sublibrary import MyClass
```

This solves the highlighting problem, but the program then gives an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.sublibraries'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I'm not sure what is the best approach to have such a simple file structure working, be able to distribute it via git and have correct hightlighting.
Should I commit .idea files so the others can import pycharm settings and use the Mark as Sources Root option?

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty `__init__.py` files in the `libraries/` and `sublibraries/` folders, which will turn these folders into (sub)packages. This will make the relative import work (and remove the highlighting).

Comment: My understanding is that `__init__` files are no longer needed in python3.

Comment: Oh, so you executed `my_library.py` as the main module, instead of `main.py`?